# Jackson serializing JAXB object gives strange results

Tags: jaxb, jackson

I have a JAXB object. When I serialize it, the results are funny! Like this =>

```
{"formData":{
"preConditions":{
    "acceptTermsAndConditions":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<acceptTermsAndConditions>true</acceptTermsAndConditions>",
    "receivePromoEmail":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<receivePromoEmail>false</receivePromoEmail>"
}, etc...
```

Whereas, the source XML just has **true** and **false** as the values:-

```
  <formData>
    <preConditions>
      <acceptTermsAndConditions>true</acceptTermsAndConditions>
      <receivePromoEmail>false</receivePromoEmail>
    </preConditions> etc...
```

My code to generate the JSON is as follows:-

```
    Application application = (Application) JAXBUtil.getXMLAsApplication();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(TypeFactory.defaultInstance());
    // make deserializer use JAXB annotations (only)
    mapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(introspector);
    // make serializer use JAXB annotations (only)
    mapper.getSerializationConfig().with(introspector);


    try {
        mapper.writeValue(new File("application.json"), application);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Where the **PreConditions** class above is generated by JAXB2 (XJC). The following is a snippet:-

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "acceptTermsAndConditions",
        "receivePromoEmail"
    })
    public static class PreConditions {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected Object acceptTermsAndConditions;
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected Object receivePromoEmail;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the acceptTermsAndConditions property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link Object }
         *     
         */
        public Object getAcceptTermsAndConditions() {
            return acceptTermsAndConditions;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the acceptTermsAndConditions property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link Object }
         *     
         */
        public void setAcceptTermsAndConditions(Object value) {
            this.acceptTermsAndConditions = value;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the value of the receivePromoEmail property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link Object }
         *     
         */
        public Object getReceivePromoEmail() {
            return receivePromoEmail;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the receivePromoEmail property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link Object }
         *     
         */
        public void setReceivePromoEmail(Object value) {
            this.receivePromoEmail = value;
        }

    }
```

Any clues on why the JSON is so crazy?

Comment: This is not enough information: can you add definition of `Application` type? My guess is that type for "acceptTermsAndConditions" and "receivePromoEmail" is a DOM document or such -- these are not POJO types, and can only be serialized as raw Strings.

Comment: Updated with information about the Application type, as requested.

Comment: Ah. Now, the problem is within `Application.FormData` (that's where "strange" JSON is in ). Could you add that too? I still think types are declared as DOM `Element` or some other XML-specific type, which can not be handled in ways other than just dumping XML.

Comment: Added Application.FormData, as requested.

Comment: How about you look at your data to understand why I ask for these... the answer is in there, matching fields that have embedded XML.

Comment: StaxMan. I'm still not getting it. The XML in there is just comments. This is just a XJC generated JAXB class??? Sorry, but I'm gonna need you to spell it out for me.

Comment: Yes, but you still have not included class that has properties that have that XML. Or indicated what the type of those fields are. It would be preferable if you would understand where the problem likely occurs, otherwise I will be asking for more info potentially indefinitely.

Comment: The class is too big to post into stackoverflow, so have just pasted in the relevant inner class 'PreConditions'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the nominal type for `acceptTermsAndConditions` is `java.lang.Object`, it is hard to know what exactly is going on. Serializer will be chosen based on runtime type on serialization -- my guess is that it would be DOM `Document`.
On deserialization it would not work too well, and would just become `java.util.Map`.

So you may need to change the schema to generate more specific types: anything with `java.lang.Object` are likely to cause issues.

You may want to see actual Java types that your object has before serialization. That should explain where the strange output comes from. I don't think it can be simple boolean value.

Comment: StaxMan - thanks for your insights. Unfortunately I cannot change the schema. I had a look at the run-time type and it's org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl, so I have solved my issue by writing a custom serializer for this type. I'm kind of surprised that the Jackson implementation didn't include this serializer, given that this is the default type generated by XJC when no type is specified in the schema.

Comment: Jackson is not a JAXB implementation, so best it can do is to serialize it as a String, which it does (there is a serializer for DOM elements). Basically, DOM elements are just another alien datatype. Custom serializer makes sense if you want to convert it to JSON structure.